# How to optimize GC for regular object allocation/deallocation in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection, three.js

After many time of research I found that one of the big hurdle in performances in my game was because of the GC's triggers. Thus I spent a lot of time optimizing were I could adding pool.

Now the performances are way better but still after some games it starts to GC a lot again. The thing is that from one game to another models are different, there is no memory leak but amount of allocated/freed memory is about 5mb between each game and most is taken by geometry.

This is a screenshot on what happens between two game reload ( the models are the same ), ~3-4mb is allocated.
[image]

I though of different solutions so maybe someone would have a better one or help me choose :

1. Keep everything in memory and reuse the meshes without freeing them ( But then a lot of memory would be taken when switching between several levels )
2. Create a sort of cache in order to keep in memory only the few last geometries (a mix between freeing all and keeping in memory). In the game you often play the same level several times so it's not that stupid IMHO.
3. Have a better geometry data management. As I did with particles, create a pool where the software can pick up Vectors and Materials instead of creating and deleting new ones each time. For particles it saved me a hell lot of memory alloc/dealloc ( hundred of thousands were allocated/freed at each game ).

The thing is that I create myself the pointClouds geometries so I have control for giving them materials and vectors of my own and putting them back in the pool on dispose. However models are using an internal way that's blurry to me at this time.

Advantage of this technic as I experienced with the particles is that it's really convenient and transparent to use. Once the background work is done every geometry and/or object created would use the global vector/material/euler/quaternion pools